# Proof : Derivative of the trace of a function

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I've come across the identity
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \text{Tr} \{F[M(x)]\}}{\partial M(x)} = F'[M(x)]^T
\end{equation}
where F' is the scalar derivative of F but I've never seen the proof of it. Does somebody know how to do it or have a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Write the Taylor series of a function of a scalar variable $x$ and its derivative
$$\eqalign{
F(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \a_kx^k, \qquad
F'(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k\a_k)x^{k-1} \\
}$$
Apply the function to a matrix argument $X$ and take the trace
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \trace{F(X)} \;=\; I:\LR{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \a_kX^k} \\
}$$
Then calculate its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
d\phi
 &= I:\LR{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\a_k\;\c{dX^{k}}} \\
 &= I:\LR{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\a_k\;\c{\sum_{j=\o}^k X^{j-\o}dX\;X^{k-j}}} \\
 &= \LR{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\a_k\;\sum_{j=\o}^k\LR{X^{j-\o}}^TI\;\LR{X^{k-j}}^T}:dX \\
 &= \LR{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\a_k\,\LR{k X^{k-\o}}}^T:dX \\
 &= F'(X)^T:dX \\
\grad{\phi}{X} &= F'(X)^T \\\\
}$$

---

In the preceding, a colon is used as a convenient product notation
for the trace, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
I:B &= \trace{I^TB} \;=\; \trace{B} \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in such a product to be rearranged in many different but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:AB &= CB^T:A = A^TC:B \\
}$$